# CCavenue payment gateway integration in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, payment-gateway, ccavenue

Has any one have integrated ccavenue payment gateway in asp.net mvc4, actually they are providing a package whose .NET version is 3.5 and i have developed an ecommerce website using .NET version 4.5? please help me out with this problem.

Comment: Hi @Prasenjith, Don't worry !!! I am here to help you. I have already integrated CC Avenue's Payment gateway in my website. Sorry, I can't answer this today. May be tomorrow.

Comment: @AbhilashPA-Pullelil waiting for your answer :)

Comment: Check this https://srimansaswat.wordpress.com/2016/11/26/how-to-integrate-ccavenue-payment-gateway-in-asp-net-mvc/
.Hope it willl help :)